# How to detect if any span contains exactly one specific class?

Tags: jquery

A page contains few spans with classes:

```
<span class="system-on blue">1</span>
<span class="system-on">4</span>
<span class="system-on blue">0</span>
```

I want to jQuery detect if any of this spans has **exactly** one class named *system-on* and then do something. I tried this way, but it doesn't work:

```
if ($('.system-on.blue').length) {               //detects spans with two classes
 //do nothing
}
else //do something
```

Comment: document.getElementById('divId').className.split(/\s+/); gets you a list of class names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean it has **only** the `system-on` class, you can use an attribute equals selector for that:

```
if ($("span[class=system-on]").length) {
    // do nothing
}
else {
    // do something
}
```

Here's an example showing the selector at work: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/OfIPUCib/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Attribute Equal Selector with Class</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="system-on blue">1</span>
  <span class="system-on">4</span>
  <span class="system-on blue">0</span>
  <script>
    $("span[class=system-on]").css("color", "red");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("span[class=system-on]")`?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Good point, the question did say "span" specifically.

Comment: @Lucas: No worries. Or I should point out that if you want spans with `system-on` but not `blue` (but possibly with other classes), you can do `$("span.system-on").not(".blue").length`. So it depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/BEjry/1/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( "span" ).each(function(  ) {
        if( $( this ).attr("class") == "system-on" ){
            alert($( this ).text());
        }
});
});
```